# Which isolation levels use MVCC in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, isolation-level, mvcc

I read [**Transaction Isolation Levels**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) in MySQL documentation. Then, only [**READ COMMITTED**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-committed) and [**REPEATABLE READ**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) talk about [**snapshot**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_snapshot) as shown below:

> - **READ COMMITTED**
>   Each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads
>   its own fresh snapshot. ...

> - **REPEATABLE READ**
>   This is the default isolation level for InnoDB. Consistent reads
>   within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first
>   read. ...

> snapshot
> A representation of data at a particular time, which remains
> the same even as changes are committed by other transactions. Used by
> certain isolation levels to allow consistent reads.

So, do only [**READ COMMITTED**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-committed) and [**REPEATABLE READ**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) use **MVCC(Multiversion concurrency control)**?

What about [**READ UNCOMMITTED**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_read-uncommitted) and [**SERIALIZABLE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_serializable)?

Answer (score 0):

All transaction isolation levels in InnoDB use MVCC.

Comment: Excellent @Bill Karwin + 1, the documentation states that `Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released` when talking about a LOCK TABLES table WRITE. If MVCC did not exist we could not even do a SELECT (read) of the table because LOCK TABLES table WRITE it is an exclusive lock on the table, right? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html @Bill Karwin

Comment: @Daniel, LOCK TABLES is not about MVCC.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin, so it is only for innodb?

Comment: Yes, InnoDB is the only storage engine included with MySQL that supports MVCC. Some third-party storage engines or RDBMS products also support MVCC, such as RocksDB, DocDB, or CockroachDB.